# Why strings are not coming in same line in ruby

Tags: ruby, string

In this code in three places i am having `puts`, Where first one prints variables in different line with the string and second one too. but 3rd one gives in same line.

```
def calliee (name,game)
        #puts("#{name}#{game} he might be a bad guy")
        return " he might be a bad guy #{name}#{game}"
    end
    def mymethod(name)
        puts("enter your last name")
        ss=gets()
        #return "#{name}"+"#{ss}"+"he might be a bad guy"
        calliee(name,ss)
    end
    puts("enter tour first name")
    tt=gets()
    #ww=mymethod(tt)
    yy=mymethod(tt)
    puts(yy)
    puts("#{tt} is 1st name")
    puts("prabhu "+"#{2+3}"+"#{4+5}")
```

i want everything in same line and i need to know why this is happening. please help

Comment: You need to strip the newline characters off of `yy` and `tt` in order to get it all on one line.  See the [Ruby tutorial](http://ruby-doc.org//docs/Tutorial/part_02/user_input.html) on getting input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Kernel#gets`](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) gives you a string with the `\n` added to the end of the *string*. That causing the output in the **multiple lines**.

To make your output as you wanted it to be, you need to use [`#chomp`](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-chomp) method, like `gets.chomp`.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to Arup's answer:

`puts` adds a newline to the end of the output. `print` does not. So you may also want to replace `puts` with `print` to have all output in one line.

Comment: I thought OP does know about the `#puts` not the `#gets`.. :p

Comment: my answer was.. "just in case"... :P

Comment: Thank you for answer..but i also wanted a reason which is already given by @Arup. Though u gave me another option so +1 for u

Comment: `puts` doesn't simply add a newline. It writes a newline after *each* argument (converting it to a string if necessary), but only if that argument does not already end with a newline. Therefore, `puts "foo", "bar\n", "baz"` writes `"foo\nbar\nbaz\n"` to stdout, resulting in 3 lines.